# Getting different results on MongoDB Same version on different OS/Machines

Tags: mongodb, azure

we are importing a csv file in mongodb version 3.4 on different local machines with ubuntu and windows os and azure Mongodb. 
After importing the file we find the same number of records in the collection machinewise.

now, we are executing certain steps on the collection in local and azure machine database which gives us different results on different machines.

Comment: I need more details to help you with your problem. Without any further details, I suspect you are experiencing encoding issues.

Comment: Your question is too vague man

Comment: Please add details of the "certain steps" you are taking and the differing results returned. Also, what sort of MongoDB deployment do you have: standalone, replica set, or sharded cluster? Lastly: can you confirm the exact versions of MongoDB server you are running locally and on Azure? Does "Azure" mean Cosmos with MongoDB protocol, or an actual MongoDB server running on Windows or Ubuntu?

Comment: thanks everyone there was an issue in my query itself